# I installed Pyyaml before Libyaml. How do I get Pyyaml to have Libyaml support?

Tags: terminal, terminal.app

I'm on macOS Sonoma. I installed Pyyaml before Libyaml by accident. I installed Pyyaml with pip and Libyaml with Homebrew.

How do I get Pyyaml to have Libyaml support? I tried uninstalling it, but it gave this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'PyYAML'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

How would I fix this?